# YII2 error ForbiddenHttpException

Tags: php, yii, yii2

When I send post query to actionAnswerTest I get an exception:

> [error] 6754#6754: *479979 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: An
>   Error  occurred while handling another error: exception
>   'yii\web\ForbiddenHttpException' with message 'You are not allowed  to
>   access this page.'

Rules in controller:

```
public function behaviors()
{
return [
    'access' => [
        'class' => AccessControl::className(),
        'rules' => [
            [
                'actions' => ['index', 'partial', 'complete', 'answer', 'answer-test'],
                'allow' => true,
                'roles' => ['@'],
            ],
        ],
        'denyCallback' => function($rule, $action) {
            return Yii::$app->getResponse()->redirect('denied')->send();
        },
    ],
    'verbs' => [
        'class' => VerbFilter::className(),
        'actions' => [
            'update' => ['post'],
            'test-partial' => ['post'],
            'test-complete' => ['post'],
            'test-answer' => ['post'],
        ],
    ],
    [
        'class' => ContentNegotiator::className(),
        'only' => ['update', 'answer'],
        'formats' => [
            'application/json' => Response::FORMAT_JSON,
        ],
    ],
];
}
```

Post query send by authorized user.

Answer (score 0):

Help rename `actionAnswerTest` to `actionAnswertest`, and `answer-test` to `answertest`